# Swift3 - Insert Relation In Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift3

I have two Entities, namely

1. Clinic
2. Department

The relationship between them is many-to-many. i.e a clinic has many departments and a department has many clinics associated.

I have setup the entities in `coredata.xcdatamodeld` and generated the `NSManagedObject` classes. PFA the graph

[image]

I have the following code which takes care of inserting departments and clinics

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import SwiftyJSON
import Kingfisher

class InstallManager {

    let moc = NetworkManager.managedObjectContext
    let data: JSON!

    init(withData data: JSON) {
        self.data = data
    }

    // Install Department
    private func installDepartment() {
        for(_,jsonData):(String, JSON) in self.data["deparment"]["list"] {
            let department = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: moc)
            department.setValue(jsonData["id"].int32, forKey: "id")
            department.setValue(jsonData["name"].string, forKey: "name")
            department.setValue(jsonData["icon"].string, forKey: "icon")
            department.setValue(jsonData["slug"].string, forKey: "slug")
            department.setValue(jsonData["revision"].int32, forKey: "revision")
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    // Install Clinic
    private func installClinic() {
        let departmentList = fetchDepartmentList()
        for (_,jsonData):(String, JSON) in self.data["clinic"]["list"] {
            let coverPictureAbsolute = "\(jsonData["cover_picture"].string!)"
            let coverPictureRelative = (coverPictureAbsolute as NSString).lastPathComponent
            let clinic = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Clinic", into: moc)
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["id"].int32, forKey: "id")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["name"].string, forKey: "name")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["slogan"].string, forKey: "slogan")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["profile"].string, forKey: "profile")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["address"].string, forKey: "address")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["telephone"].string, forKey: "telephone")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["email"].string, forKey: "email")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["website"].string, forKey: "website")
            clinic.setValue(coverPictureRelative, forKey: "cover_picture")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["latitude"].string, forKey: "latitude")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["longitude"].string, forKey: "longitude")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["slug"].string, forKey: "slug")
            clinic.setValue(jsonData["revision"].int32, forKey: "revision")

            let clinicEntity = clinic.value(forKeyPath: "departments") as! Clinic
            for department in departmentList {
                clinicEntity.addToDepartments(department)
                print(department.name!)
            }

            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchDepartmentList() -> [Department] {
        var departmentList:[Department]!
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Department> = Department.fetchRequest()
        do {
            departmentList = try moc.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Cannot fetch clinics list \(error)")
        }
        return departmentList
    }

    public func install() {
        self.installDepartment()
        self.installClinic()
    }
}
```

My problem is while inserting relations between clinic and departments, I have the list of department ids which I want to set relation with the clinic. As you can see in the above code, I tried the following code

```
let departmentList = fetchDepartmentList()
let clinicEntity = clinic.value(forKeyPath: "departments") as! Clinic
for department in departmentList {
    clinicEntity.addToDepartments(department)
    print(department.name!)
}
```

But the line clinicEntity throws me the following error

```
Could not cast value of type '_NSFaultingMutableSet' to 'APP.Clinic'
```

What is the issue here? How can I set the relation?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the auto-generated classes from core-data (NSManagedObject SubClass)

```
// filename: Clinic.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Clinic)
public class Clinic: NSManagedObject {

}

// filename: Clinic+CoreDataProperties
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Clinic {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Clinic> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Clinic>(entityName: "Clinic");
    }

    @NSManaged public var address: String?
    @NSManaged public var cover_picture: String?
    @NSManaged public var email: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: Int32
    @NSManaged public var latitude: NSDecimalNumber?
    @NSManaged public var longitude: NSDecimalNumber?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var profile: String?
    @NSManaged public var revision: Int32
    @NSManaged public var slogan: String?
    @NSManaged public var slug: String?
    @NSManaged public var telephone: String?
    @NSManaged public var website: String?
    @NSManaged public var departments: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for departments
extension Clinic {

    @objc(addDepartmentsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToDepartments(_ value: Department)

    @objc(removeDepartmentsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromDepartments(_ value: Department)

    @objc(addDepartments:)
    @NSManaged public func addToDepartments(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeDepartments:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromDepartments(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `to-many` relationship you need to get the `mutableSetValueForKey` because the type is `NSSet` rather than `Clinic`.

```
let clinicEntity = clinic.mutableSetValue(forKey: "departments")
for department in departmentList {
    clinicEntity.add(department)
    print(department.name!)
}
```

or simpler

```
let clinicEntity = clinic.mutableSetValue(forKey: "departments")
clinicEntity.addObjects(from: departmentList)
```

To use the autogenerated method you can replace

```
let clinicEntity = clinic.value(forKeyPath: "departments") as! Clinic
   for department in departmentList {
   clinicEntity.addToDepartments(department)
      print(department.name!)
   }
```

with

```
clinic.addToDepartments(NSSet(array: departmentList))
```

PS: I'd recommend to use the more convenient dot notation, for example

```
department.id = jsonData["id"].int32
department.name = jsonData["name"].string
department.icon = jsonData["icon"].string
department.slug = jsonData["slug"].string
department.revision = jsonData["revision"].int32
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I wonder what is the use of the method `@NSManaged public func addToDepartments(_ value: Department)` which is available in class generated by core-data (NSManagedObject)

Comment: I haven't noticed that these methods are autogenerated. Perfect, use them instead of `mutableSetValueForKey`

Comment: Thats the part, I cannot. It throws me the error, I have updated my question with the two classes it auto-generated.

Comment: PS: Since you are using `NSManagedObject` subclass anyway why don't you write  `clinic.name = jsonData["name"].string` rather than `clinic.setValue(jsonData["name"].string, forKey: "name")`?

Comment: That would be awesome If I can do it, but because clinic is an instance of NSEntityDescription, how do I make this to work? can you help me with an example?

Comment: You are giving me the exact code I used :-) check my question, this for some insane reason throws me an error `Could not cast value of type '_NSFaultingMutableSet' to 'APP.Clinic` let me retry this and let you know.

Comment: You are not using the exact code: `clinic.value(forKeyPath: "departments") as! Clinic` does not work because – once again –  `departments` is `NSSet`  (many) rather than `Clinic` (one).

Comment: I see your point, but there are two methods with name addToDepartments with different arguments, one with Department and other with NSSet, what I tried was with Department.